# why dbghelp.h's symbol related functions always return 126 error code?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dbghelp

When i try to use the functions SymbolFromName() e  SymbolFromAddress() the return code always return 126 (MODULE_NOT_FOUND), the code is :

```
    #include<dbghelp.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <debugapi.h>
    #include <WinBase.h>
    
    using namespace std;

    int main(){
    DWORD  error;
    HANDLE hProcess;

    SymSetOptions(SYMOPT_UNDNAME | SYMOPT_DEFERRED_LOADS);

    hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();

    if (!SymInitialize(hProcess, NULL, TRUE))
    {
        // SymInitialize failed
        error = GetLastError();
        cout << "SymInitialize returned error " << error << endl;;
        return FALSE;
    }}
    

    hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();

    SymSetOptions(SYMOPT_UNDNAME | SYMOPT_DEFERRED_LOADS);
    SymInitialize(hProcess, NULL, TRUE);

    TCHAR szSymbolName[MAX_SYM_NAME];
    ULONG64 buffer[(sizeof(SYMBOL_INFOW) +
        MAX_SYM_NAME * sizeof(TCHAR) +
        sizeof(ULONG64) - 1) /
        sizeof(ULONG64)];
    PSYMBOL_INFO pSymbol = (PSYMBOL_INFO)buffer;

    _tcscpy_s(szSymbolName, MAX_SYM_NAME, TEXT("mainCRTStartup")); // i  
    know the entrypoint name by using >>nm command in windows for extract 
    symbol
    pSymbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
    pSymbol->MaxNameLen = MAX_SYM_NAME;

    if (SymFromName(hProcess, szSymbolName, pSymbol)){
       cout << pSybol->address
    } // this return always 126

    }
```

i use VisualStudio and the default debugger for testing it.
Part of the code above is taken from MSDN documentation, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/retrieving-symbol-information-by-name).

EDIT : i know the main simbol thanks to [nm](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/nm.1.asp), that can extract a list of symbols, in my case it contains :

```
 00401300 T _WinMainCRTStartup
 00401460 T _main
 004012e0 T _mainCRTStartup
```

I also try to using different symbols name like main, mainCRTStartup, wWinMain, WinMain and so on, without any results

Comment: I can reproduce this, but if I replace `"WinMainCRTStartup"` with `"main"`, it works.

Comment: Are you sure your exe file contains the symbol `WinMainCRTStartup`? A console program doesn't use this symbol, but it uses `mainCRTStartup` instead.

Comment: i also try main, wmain, mainCRTSurtup, wmainCRTSurtup and also others, with any results

Comment: It's `mainCRTStartup `, not `mainCRTSurtup`, check that. Otherwise [edit] and show a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it's still not a [MCVE]. Latter is a piece of code I can copy/paste and run in my Visual Studio.

Comment: just cecked, i'm sure that the entrypoint is mainCRTStartup and also in the program there is also a main() function (i saw it by using debugger) but none of names return a different result.
the problem, i think, is not on the name of symbol that i use

Comment: BTW what is `nm`? I don't have `nm.exe` on my computer. it doesn't sound likke a Microsoft tool-

Comment: In your code you still have `WinMainCRTStartup` instead of `mainCRTStartup`. Does it work with `mainCRTStartup`? Anyway post a [MCVE]

Comment: now is a minimal reproducile example, as i just say i also try mainCRTStartup and also only main, but with no result.

Comment: Your code does not compile

Comment: There are some errors in your code (although just some header files and parentheses). After I fixed the problem, `mainCRTStartup` worked fine for me but `WinMainCRTStartup` didn't. So are you sure your exe file contains the symbol `WinMainCRTStartup`?

Comment: the example above is not complete but i also try to using mainCRTStartup and also other combinations and symbols name but with the same result: MODULE_NOT_FOUND (err code 126), maybe the problem is that the loading of the symbol in memory is deferred until the "request" for the particular symbol.
but i'm not sure of that, i'm sure that the problem is not on the parameters of the function

Comment: what windows version do you have ? and also x86 or x64?

Comment: Both x86 and x64 work fine for me.

Comment: Can you confirm whether you are using UNICODE encoding or multi-byte encoding, and whether you have forced `szSymbolName` in the `SymFromName` function?

Comment: i use multi-byte encoding but i also try with UNICODE, i don't think that i'm forced to use some particular encoding, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-symfromname) doesn't specify that

Comment: The sample also works for me.